# Is it more efficient to pass an object or a variable?

Tags: python, performance

I'm creating a hangman game in Python 2, and I can store the current word in either:

- An object, as an attribute (like `wordlist.word = blah`)
- A variable (like `word = blah`)

I'm then passing this word into another function, where the main parts of the game reside, to be used in comparisons and such.

I kind of prefer to keep the current word in an object, since it makes sense to me to group it under that class and seems cleaner by keeping all that together, but I'm afraid that since an object has more code in it it takes more effort for the program to pass it around.

Is it more efficient to use an object or a variable? What are the pros and cons of either? For example, is one more efficient/quicker than the other?

Comment: everything is an object in python.  EVERYTHING.  The underlying code stores everything as a "PyObject".  Your mixing value types with reference types, and in your case it depends on how it will be used.  Since your variables will be passed by reference no matter what, it is up to you decide whatever is easiest for your mental map.

Comment: Fctn(wordlist.word) is trivially more expensive because python looks up wordlist and then word. But they are the same otherwise. This level of optimization is rarely useful because there are a huge number of lookups and you are probably suboptimal in other places too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apples and oranges. You should think about program flow and structure when choosing between storing data in a scope variable or an instance attribute. Comparing performance here is meaningless.

If the data logically belongs to an entity in your program which will be passed around between different parts of the program (which seems to be the case here), create a class and put the data in an instance of this class. Eg. the current word might be an attribute of the current `Round`, or `Game`, depending on how fine grained you want your objects to be.

If, on the other hand, the data is only used within the scope of the current method, use a scope variable.